# A piece of string

Tags: riddle, rhyme

"For a puzzle quite absurd,

Find one and an extra word:

They can both describe some string,

But they'll mean a different thing.

Lastly, split one into three.

Change the second, you'll be free."

Good luck, i will mark the correct answer when someone gets it.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/RandomActsOfTf2/comments/chhb92/giveaway_fixed_riddle_for_handy_canes_giveaway/

Comment: Hi GhostDog98, welcome to Puzzling SE!.  I also see this riddle on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/RandomActsOfTf2/) is this your puzzle or did you get it from somewhere else?  If so, you would need to source it and make sure you have permission to post it.

Comment: Cheers @SteveV, forgot about that; to be honest i don't even play video games, just interested in how others might answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be from an ongoing competition, which are not allowed on Puzzling.SE, even with proper attribution.  For more info:  https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests/1675#1675